# Trying to do a simple sed substitution but I'm confused about what needs to be escaped

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have this string: `'$'nwnwnwnnn`

And want to change it to: `{ bitset<9>(0bnwnwnwnnn), '$'},`

I've looked at many similar questions for different shells using their methods but nothing has worked. I'm generally in zsh but I can use bash or another shell.

The general form I've been trying is this:

```
sed -E -i new s/(\'.\')([nw]+)/{ bitset<9>(0b\2), \1},/g thing.txt
```

It should work for any character other than `$` and any sequence of `n` or `w`.

I'm generally confused as to what I need to escape here. Some answers on this site said to escape the parenthesis in the first part of the substitution.

Am I using `-i` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the parentheses to create a capture group if you're using basic regexp, you don't escape them if you're using extended regexp. The `-E` option to GNU `sed`, and the `-r` option to standard `sed`, enable extended regexp, so you don't need to escape them.

If you only want to match `$` rather than allow any character in the quotes, you need an escaped `$`.

You need to put the entire `s///` command inside quotes, as it must be a single argument to the `sed` command.

When using `-i`, it's conventional to put a `.` before the suffix. Also, the suffix is put on the saved copy of the original file, not the new file that you're creating with the changes, so `new` is a poor suffix.

```
sed -E -i .bak "s/('\$')([nw]+)/{ bitset<9>(0b\2), \1},/g" thing.txt
```

Comment: This worked for me but only when I used double quotes instead of single quotes around the regex command and stopped escaping the single quotes. Thanks

Comment: I always forget which shell quotes allow escaping quotes inside them :)